# Range.Find method in Excel VBA returning wrong row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search a string in excel using VBA .. for ex.
My sheet contains data as follows

```
1.Lalit
2.Lalit
```

If there is only one row with occurrence of `lalit` it gives correct result while if there is 2 row with same string it returning the 2nd one as result instead of first. Please help me how to return correct row.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN article about Range.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) you can specify which cell after which you want to start the search. You can also specify the search direction. Assuming you have a Range of `A1:A500` and you want to find the first instance of `Latit` you could use:

```
Range("A1:A500").Find("Test", Range("A500"), , , xlByRows, xlNext).Row
```

That starts the search at `A500`, which will wrap automatically to the first row. Excel returns the first result it can find, so you'll get `1` as the answer (Assuming `Latit` is in `A1`)

Answer (score 0):

On largely the same basis as JNevill but ensuring

- the search starts after the last cell in column A (ie starts from A1)
- handles "no match" - which `Find` should always be tested with

*code*

```
Sub FindEx()
Dim strFind As String
Dim rng1 As Range

strFind = "Lalit"
Set rng1 = Cells.Find(strFind, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlPart, , xlNext)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox "first value of " & strFind & " found in " & rng1.Address(0, 0)

End Sub
```